# Difference between int * array[60] and int * array = new int(60);

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
int * array[60]; //creates an array of 60 pointers to an int
int * array = new int(60); //same thing?
```

Do these both result in the same type of array? e.g an array of pointers to integers

I know that the first one uninitialized,  and the second one is initialized, but I am unsure of what exactly the second one creates.

Comment: The second one isn't even an array, it's a single `int` object. To create an array of `int*` with `new`, you'd be looking at `int** array = new int[60]`.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that now, for some reason I thought that it would create an array. But I read the documentation and the first parameter of the int constructor becomes the value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int * array = new int(60); //same thing?
```

No, they're not the same thing. `array` is just a pointer here, and then point to an int with initialized value `60`.

If you meant `int * array = new int[60];`, `array` will point to an array of 60 ints, they're still not the same thing.

Note that just as the declaration, `int* array` means it is a *pointer*, while `int* array[60]` means it is an *array* (of 60 pointers). (Array might decay to pointer, i.e. `int**` for `int* array[60]`, it's not same as `int*`.)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you do not realize that the second case is not an array, the following program prints `60`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int* foo = new int(60);
    std::cout << *foo << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two pictures that illustrate the differences between

```
int * array[5];
```

and

```
int * array = new int(5);
```

To create a pointer int **array** use `int * array = new int[5];`

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgiWz.png),

[debug view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gs3WF.png)

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be new int[5], new int(5) only creates a pointer of an int of value 5

Answer (score 0):

One of them creates an array, the other doesn't.

```
int * array[60]; // Creates an array of 60 integer pointers
```

Answer (score -1):

To help understand the difference, take into account that the first line creates a 60 pointers-block in memory (in the stack if you are inside main, for example), but the second one only a pointer block.

Both are completely different types. For example, try the following:

```
array++;
```

In the first line, it does not work. In the second one, it's ok. If you try:

```
array[0]++;
```

In the first line you change the first pointer, in the second one you add 1 to the integer (change to 61).